# how to add character between columns on stimulsoft report

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I want to add "+" character between columns on stimulsoft report
But I dont know what to do

Data Fetch From SqlServer Directly

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq7OU.png)

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItXHx.png)

The Red signs is what i want

Thanks